# Javascript arrays how to print sorted elements

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, sorting, filter

I have a question about arrays. I'm new to javascript and I'm writing a program that has a function where it filters 20 elements of an array by category. That is, I have 3 buttons where, by clicking on one of them, the function is turned on and it starts displaying the filtered elements. Please tell me how can this be done? I have already tried a bunch of ways, but in the end nothing happened, although I think that I made a mistake somewhere.

array:

```
window.products = [
  {
    id: "i8",
    title: "Iphone 8",
    description:
      "The iPhone 8 ",
    price: 19900,
    discontinued: false,
    categories: ["c1"]
  },
  {
    id: "i10",
    title: "Iphone X",
    description: "Iphone 10",
    price: 39900,
    discontinued: false,
    categories: ["c1"]
  },
  {
    id: "i11",
    title: "Iphone 11",
    description: "The iPhone 11 ",
    price: 69900,
    discontinued: false,
    categories: ["c1"]
  };
```

my function

```
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("selected-category").innerHTML = "Iphones";
  document.getElementById("category-products").innerHTML = "";
  for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    document.getElementById("category-products").innerHTML = window.id;
    const found = window.products.find(window.products.categories == "c1");
    console.log(found);
  }
}
```

part html code with button

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Iphones</button>
```

Comment: Read the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have syntax error in your `windows.products = [ ... };`. It's not closed properly (you need a `]` before the `};`.

Then, the `find` method needs to be passed a function that processes an element of the Array. 
What you tried `window.products.categories == "c1"` evaluates to false, because the property `categories` does not exist in the `window.products` array. You get `undefined` on the left hand side and a string on the right hand side, so it's always `false`. You'd get "false is not a function".

Examples of using find() with a function:
`const found = window.products.find( element => element.categories == "c1" );`

 or

```
const found = window.products.find( function(element) {
    return element.categories == "c1"
});
```

But then:

1. The above `== "c1"` isn't what you should use, because it only matches due to type coercion from an array to a string, and only matches when the categories has only "c1" and no other elements. You should use `includes` method.
2. "find" will only give you one matching product. Use "filter" to find all matching ones.

   If you only need to search for one key "c1", you can use
   `const found = window.products.filter( product=> product.categories.includes("c1"));` and for two keys "c1" and "c2": `const found = window.products.filter( product => product.categories.includes("c1") && product.categories.includes("c2"));`
   But I don't think you should use the above, because you should handle the case where the user searches for multiple keys.

```
const searchList = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']
const found = window.products.filter ( function( product) {
//returns true if element.categories contains all of 'c1', 'c2' and 'c3'
 return searchList.every( searchKey => product.categories.includes(searchKey)) ;
})
```

You can also do the search in one line, but may be harder to read :

```
const searchList = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']
const found = window.products.filter ( product => searchList.every( searchKey => product.categories.includes(searchKey)) );
```